# How to know if DBCC SHRINKFILE was executed?

Tags: sql-server

How to know if DBCC SHRINKFILE was executed in your database in last 24 hrs?

Comment: Why do you want to know? Are you trying to find who called this and caused file fragmentation, or do you want to call it whether it's needed or not once per day? Shouldn't you ask this at `dba.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129526/sql-server-history-of-growth-and-shrink-events

Comment: Shrinking a database or log should be done only if absolutely necessary. Otherwise it *harms* performance - it can cause file fragmentation *and* waste CPU and IO next time the database or log file needs to grow. It will have to reallocate the space that was deleted by shrinking.

Comment: I have an ETL process, at the end of which this command is executed , the ETL process sends an email if there is failure ,and I got an email even if the process finished successfully , that's why I was wondering if the DBCC SHRINKFILE is causing the failure email. I'm not a Database admin , so I don't know much about the DBCC commands

Comment: You absolutely should NOT just blindly run this at the end of an ETL process. As @PanagiotisKanavos already stated this is going to do more harm than good. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/

Comment: In the past the log file growth has caused issues so this was suggested by a db admin only , I can't comment if its right or wrong in this scenario since I don't have access to all the details

Comment: I just need to know if there was any error while executing that command and rest will be taken care

Comment: Instead of trying to shrink the log, *reduce* log usage. *Don't* insert rows one by one, even with TVPs. Use BULK INSERT, SqlBulkCopy or minimally-logged operations. Use a separate staging database in the simple or bulk logged mode and pass only the final data to the production database

Comment: Fix your error reporting, then. The best place to know if a statement is causing a failure is at the exact spot the statement is executed. Trying to find out if an arbitrary command was executed in the past 24 hours is exactly the wrong angle from which to approach the issue (nor would it help you to fix the underlying issue in any way if you found out that it was or was not executed).